Prove whether $x_n=\frac{2^n+n^{2^n}}{(-3)^{3n}-3}$ converges or diverges
Q. Prove whether $x_n=\frac{2^n+n^{2^n}}{(-3)^{3n}-3}$ converges or diverges.
Could I please get some help on this sequence question? I have been stuck for far too long now, and cannot manage to do this rigorously without relying on handwaving, leading me to think that there are some results that I have not learnt yet.
Edit:
Elaborating on @geetha290krm's comment below, I have the following:
We use the fact that if $(x_n)$ converges, then it must be bounded, so contrapositively, if it is unbounded, then it must diverge.
This is equivalent to saying $|x_n|\to \infty$, or, $|x_n|\geq M_n$ and $M_n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$. That is, for any $K>0$, we can choose $N$ such that $M_n>K$ for all $n≥N$, and hence $|x_n|>K$.
By the triangle inequality, we have $|(-3)^{3n}-3|\leq |(-3)^{3n}|+3=27^n+3\iff \frac1{|(-3)^{3n}-3|}\geq \frac1{27^n+3}\geq \frac1{2(27^n)}$.
Thus, $|x_n|\geq \frac{n^{2n}}{3^{3n}}=\frac{(n^n)^2}{2(27)^n}\to \infty$  since $\frac{n^n}{b^n}\to \infty$  for all $b>0$.
Is this working ok?

$|x_n|>\frac {n^{2^n}} {2(3^{2n})}>\frac {n^{2n}} {2(3^{2n})} \to \infty$.

Can you elaborate on your handwave solution? Maybe we can start from there

Factor the terms of higher degree on numerator and on denominator. Now there are terms that to go $0$ and others to $1$ and you can evaluate the limit.

@geetha290krm ohhh, because it shows that it is unbounded, and hence cannot converge right?

Include in a question what u have tried to solve a problem

$n^{2^n}$ looks massive to me compared to the other 3 terms.

A quick answer can be seen as this :
$$ x_n=\dfrac{2^nn^{2n}}{(-3)^{3n}-3}$$
So it is equivalent to so that :
$$ |x_n| \sim\left |\dfrac{2^nn^{2^n}}{(-3)^{3n}}\right| $$
And clearly $ (-3)^{3n} = o(n^{2^n})$, so that :
$$ |x_n| \to \infty $$

Why downvote ??
